# Prove by induction summation with exp index

Tags: summation, induction

Hello I am new with induction and I am stuck on this summation

$\sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} > \frac{n+3}{4}$

The $2^n$ confuses me

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Hey .. welcome to MSE. What hav you tried so far ?

Comment: You should  show us your efforts so that we can assist you further.

Comment: Have you tried writing down what it means concretely for $n=1,2,3?$  That may clear it up for you.

Comment: I tried $\sum_{i=1}^{2^(n+1)} \frac{1}{(2i-1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{2i-1} + \frac{1}{2*2^(n+1)-1}$ but it led me to more clues

Answer (score 0):

You are adding up terms from $1$ to $2^n$

For the induction when you change n to n+1 you will have new terns from $2^n+1$ all the way up to $2^{n+1}$